# Single Crossing Condition (Milgrom Shannon 1994)

Tags: functions

I have solved an optimization problem $\max_x f(x,a)$ and I am now doing comparative statics in the parameter $a$. I basically want to know if the argmax is monotone in $a$.

I am trying to understand the single crossing property in Milgrom Shannon (1994).

According to Theorem 4: Let $f:X\times A\to\mathbb{R}$. Then $argmax f(x,t)$ is monotone nondecreasing in $a$ if and only if f is quasisupermodular in $x$ and satisfies the single crossing property in $(x; a)$.

I understand the if part: If $f$ satisfies the single crossing property in $(x; a)$, then $argmax f(x,a)$ is monotone nondecreasing in $a$. I see that graphically.

The other direction it is not clear to me: If $argmax f(x,a)$ is monotone nondecreasing in $a$, then $f$ satisfies the single crossing property in $(x,a)$.

I think i found an example that i think it does not satisfy the single crossing, but the arg max is monotone:

Let $a\ge0$ and consider de function $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ where $f(x)=\max\left(x\left(a-x\right),0\right)$.

It is clear that the argmax $x^*=a/2$ is monotone in $a$. But, does it satisfy the Single Crossing Condition in $(x,a)$? It should, but i am not able to show it formally.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are fixing the domain of the $\arg \max$ to be all the set X.  The theorem for **two** real valued functions is

Suppose $X \subseteq \mathbb R$. Then $\arg \max_{x \in S} g(x) \geq \arg \max_{x \in S} f(x)$ for all $S \subseteq X$ if and only if $g \succeq_{sc} f$.

You are fixing $S = X$.